# MongoDB/Mongoose Security for a MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm currently learning how to use react, so i'm creating a blog using a MERN stack.
The blog only has 1 admin user to post on it, and I wanted to know, how do I secure the mongoose calls? as anyone using postman can use the URIs to post / delete, right? Im still a bit new to security and such so i'm trying to make sure that I understand how this works. How would I make it that somebody can't just use postman to create new posts if they know the URI, and only the 1 admin of the blog can?

Comment: The URI alone isn't enough, they'll have to pass a valid authentication token too.

Comment: Is that built into mongoose / mongodb / express? Because I haven't added anything to do with auth yet

Comment: Get an authentication middleware for Express.